# Отправить переменную из кода в Jenkins

Tags: ruby, jenkins, global-variables

**Описание:**
Имеется программа на Ruby (допустим, калькулятор) и Jenkins. В качестве параметров перед запуском задачи на Jenkins я задаю любое первое число (пусть будет переменная FIRST) и любое второе число (переменная SECOND). Программа считает сумму этих чисел. После прогона Jenkins я хочу отправить Email через Editable Email Notification Plugin. В тексте письма необходимо вставить результат отработки программы (в моём случае результат сложения). Этот результат я хочу отправить из кода Ruby. В коде я могу достать переменные, отправленные через Jenkins, с помощью ENV['название переменной']. Точно так же я могу назначать переменные (ENV['RESULT'] = ...).

**Суть проблемы:**
Плагин Editable Email Notification (как, скорее всего, и все плагины в послесборочных шагах) видит ТОЛЬКО переменные, которые были указаны в параметрах Jenkins при запуске. Любые другие переменные (даже если они инициализировались через команду CMD SET в шаге перед сборкой) плагин не видит.
Пытался обратиться как $переменная - без результатов. Пытался как ${переменная} - аналогично. И даже пытался ${env.переменная}. Видит только $BUILD_NUMBER, $WORKSPACE, $JOB_NAME и другие, в том числе мои $FIRST и $SECOND.
**Как мне сохранить в переменную что-либо из кода программы и получить это в триггерах после прогона?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кажется, нужен EnvInject плагин https://stackoverflow.com/q/10625259/322020

(глупая автоматика преобразовывает этот ответ в коммент)